# Groovy code not returning true for folders

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

groovy code for jenkinspipeline to check for directory or not, is giving false even if it is directoy.

```
def folderExists(folderName) {
    if(fileExists(folderName))
    {
      def file = new File(folderName)
      echo "file/folder exists: "+folderName
      echo "Is directry "+ file.isDirectory().toString()
      return file.isDirectory()
    }
    else{
        echo "Not found: "+folderName
        return false
    }
     
}
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: What are the echos printing? It works like this in groovy - might be either a jenkins thing or folderName is not what you expect.

Comment: `fileExists(folderName)` what is this?

Comment: Do you know jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, Java's `File` object either won't work in sandboxed mode, or will run only on master node. If you want to check for folder on a slave node, you need to invoke Pipeline methods, or pure shell.

Comment: It is able to show whether files exist or not using fileExists() not File.Exists()
But it is always giving false for file.isDirectory()

Comment: Pure shell means with shell commands in the sh block right? I am running on windows so I will run with bat block, but how to fetch the result then(either true/false)?

Comment: You can print `"directory"` or `"not_directory"` in your `bat` script, fetch the results with `returnStdout: true` and analyze what's printed.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me. You had `echo` instead of `println`, I'm not au fait with Groovy in Jenkins but in pure Groovy there is no echo that I am aware of. Also, i moved the statement `def file = new File(folderName)` to before the if decision.

```
def folderExists(folderName) {
    def file = new File(folderName)
    if(file.exists())
    {
      println "file/folder exists: "+folderName
      println "Is directry "+ file.isDirectory().toString()
      return file.isDirectory()
    }
    else{
        println "Not found: "+folderName
        return false
    }
     
}

println folderExists('C:\\temp')
```

Comment: With this code it is failing to check the file.exists() itself. Not found: C:\Build-war\MartAdmin
But the folder is there

Comment: Did you use \\ in the path ?

Comment: That code worked on my machine, I tested it before I posted the answer. I think you need to give more details. Perhaps update your original question.

Comment: I am running it with jenkins pipeline, not with groovy runtime directly